# Search for messages from non-contacts in Gmail

Tags: search, gmail, contacts

I'd like to clean up my Gmail inbox and want to search for messages from people who are not in my contacts.

Ideally it would be something like:

```
-from:(is:contact)
```

but `is:contact` isn't an actual advanced search operator/value.

Answer (score 2):

It's not the most efficient way, but you get results.

Export your Gmail contacts into a .csv
Extract the names from the .csv (with Google Docs)
Create a massive filter with all the names
`from: -(name1 OR name2 OR name3)`

This last step will probably be best done with a string/file manipulation macro/script. If you'd like to try it, I can write one in [AutoHotKey](http://www.autohotkey.com/).

Comment: Do filters have a real or practical limit? I've got _hundreds_ of contacts.

Comment: I've found vague answers indicating ~1500 characters. You may have to perform multiple filters. For example, filter out your closest friends and put the mail into a different folder, then take out mailing lists, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I've been searching for the same thing recently, and it looks like not much has changed.

The closest thing Google makes available is the `has:circle` advanced search operator.

[According to Google](https://support.google.com/mail/answer/7190), `has:circle` will:

> Search for all messages that were sent from someone who you added to your Google+ circles