# Gmail search filter "from: contacts" possible?

Tags: gmail, gmail-search

In Gmail we can filter our search term to a single contact (John Smith) by using the filter `search-term from: johnsmith@gmail.com`.

Is there anyway to change the search filter to *all* my contacts instead of only a single contact?

Answer (score 5):

The closest thing I can find among the [advanced Gmail search operators](https://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190&topic=1668965&ctx=topic) is the `has:circle` operator.

> Search for all messages that were sent from someone who you added to your Google+ circles
>
> Example: `has:circle`
>
> Meaning: Any message that was sent by a person in any of your circles.

So, if all of your contacts are in a Google+ Circle this'll work for you. Unfortunately there's no `is:contact` operator.

Comment: Ugh. G+ and G-Mail are not the same thing.

Comment: @Michael: Yes, I know that. But G+ Circles are now displayed in your contacts. Blame Google.

Comment: Oh, yeah -- no blame to you. While I like G+, I'm still annoyed at how Google tries to force it on us, especially when it is inappropriate.

Comment: Well, they're not really forcing it on us anymore. They've decoupled quite a bit.

Answer (score 4):

Basically, you can't. There is no such wildcard filter or search operator for gmail. The list of valid gmail search operators can be found here: http://support.google.com/mail/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=7190.

One guy on Webapps has asked the opposite ([mail from contacts NOT in address book](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26881/search-for-messages-from-non-contacts-in-gmail)). He couldn't do that either.

I haven't found anything to solve your problem:

- 3rd party search apps (not allowed)
- Desktop mail clients (like Outlook) with addins EDIT: Thunderbird can actually do it (You don't even need an add-in)
- in Gmail Labs.

If it can be done, you'll probaly have to build it yourself (Outlook macro or a Greasemonkey script).

Answer (score 2):

You can make a filter in this format:

```
from:({"Katherine Jones" <katherine@Jones.com>, "Stan Jones" <stan@jones.com>, etc…})
```

I dump all the addresses into Word and edit there to make a format like this. The limitation is that it can take only so many addresses per filter, so I have a filter for names A-D, another filter for E-K, etc. I don't know how many characters it will take, but put them all in and an error will show you the limitation. Then chop your addresses into blocks to fit that limitation. I get about 25 addresses/filter.

Comment: Upvoted as adding the curly brackets does the trick. You can add your desired contacts into a group, then filter from this group, and add the brackets around to apply the filter for any email in the set.

Answer (score 1):

You can group all your contacts in a contact group and filter by contact group in Gmail. 
This requires knowledge of python, however. Below is the Python code used:

```
original = '[insert email addresses copied from the contact group]'
replaceComma = original.replace(",", " OR")
result = re.sub(r'".*?"', '', replaceComma)
print result
```

Comment: Your link now leads to a page laden with adult entertainment advertisements.

Answer (score 0):

I believe that

```
-has:circle
```

will exclude all email from accounts not in your circle

Comment: FWIW, this search works in the searchbox for searching mail but not in the from: field for filtering rules. Am trying this now, ending up just manually adding people I want to whitelist.

Answer (score 0):

If you really, really need this feature you could download your e-mails with Thunderbird.

Thunderbird can filter by address book and you can have multiple address books.